# Gitflow, how to handle in CI server a release branch publish with conflict with develop

Tags: git, git-flow

Imagine this situation:

[image]

The commit pointed to by the red arrow is merged into `develop` after the `release` branch is opened, but we want to **publish the `release` without that commit**.

If there is a conflict when merging `release` into `develop`, how is this handled in a CI server if we want to do this automatically?

Is it acceptable to merge into the master branch while the merge into develop is pending due to conflicts?  Or there is no merge into `master` and should to be done manually?

Answer (score 0):

If you get conflicts the merge is stopped until you resolve those conflicts so the merge commit with the red arrow isn't created.